# Clear Repeat Control

Tags: xpages

I have a custom search where a user enters a Serial Number and documents from a Notes database are returned pertaining to that S/N in a Repeat Control. They are allowed to do another search based on a different S/N, however, if a user enters a bad serial number after getting results from a good S/N the onClick code errors out and the repeat control displays documents from the good S/N.  Is there a way to erase the entries in the Repeat Control when the user starts a new search.

There are two buttons on the XPage.  The first one is named "Search" and when it is clicked, some parsing takes place (this is where it would error out w/ bad S/N) and a java bean search code is activated to return results. The "Search" button is then hidden and a second button named "New Search" is displayed which when clicked it erases data the user entered for the first search and allows them to enter a new S/N.

I've search this forum and others and found no answers.  I've set the repeat control properties RemoveRepeat to true and also repeatControls to false.

Code for Search Button

```
importPackage(com.ourComp)
dBar.warn("pssrl1 = " + getComponent("pssrl1").getValue().toUpperCase());
if(getComponent("pssrl1").getValue().toUpperCase()!=""){
try{
    var serialNbr = getComponent("pssrl1").getValue().toUpperCase();
    varr mhpItem = getDataBean.getModelNbrData(serialNbr.toUpperCase(),"americas", sessionScope.SNtable);
    sessionScope.serialNbr = serialNbr;
//it errors out below on bad S/N
    var sg= utilBean.getLeftDataInfo(searchMHP);
    var newSearchMHP = utilBean.getRightDataInfo(searchMHP);
    var funct = utilBean.getLeftDataInfo(newSearchMHP);
    var len = sg.length-1
    var size = sg.slice(0,len)
    var gen = sg.substr(len,1);
    //based on funct > lookup productFamily in another DB
    var otherDBname = configBean.getValue("otherDbPath")
    var otherDB:NotesDatabase = session.getDatabase(session.getServerName(), otherDBname);
    var vwWOther:NotesView = otherDB.getView("ProdFamLU");
    //now that we have connection to other get document based funct
    var docFunct:NotesDocument = vwOther.getDocumentByKey(funct);
    var productFamily=docFunct.getItemValueString("Family");

    returnMapSearch =  searchLiteratureBean.processSearch5(mhpItem,funct,size,gen,sessionScope.LanguageP,productFamily);
} catch(e){
    dBar.error("Error in Search button: " + e.toString());
    sessionScope.showResults = false
    println("ccDataEntry---username " + session.getEffectiveUserName() + "--> Error in Search button: " + e.toString());
}
}
println("++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
```

Code for New Search button

```
sessionScope.serialNbr="";
sessionScope.mhpItem="";
getComponent("pssrl1").setValue("");
```

How can I clear out existing results on a repeat control?

Repeat Code

```java
<xp:panel id="panelSearchResults1" styleClass="row">
        <xp:this.rendered><![CDATA[#{javascript:sessionScope.showResults != false}]]></xp:this.rendered>
<xp:repeat id="repeat1"
    rows="${searchLiteratureBean.maxResultsPerPage}"
    value="#{javascript:if(showWidget==true) {return searchLiteratureBean.getSearchResults();}}"
    var="col" indexVar="ind">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <xp:image
                url="#{col.iconURL}" id="image2" alt="#{col.mediaType}"
                style="padding-top:3px;">
            </xp:image>
            <xe:tooltip
                id="tooltip1" for="image1" label="#{col.mediaType}">
            </xe:tooltip>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xp:link escape="true" text="#{col.subject}" id="link2" value="#{col.url}">
                <xp:this.target><![CDATA[#{javascript:return (col.isHomeDoc()? "" : "_blank");}]]></xp:this.target>
            </xp:link>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField6" value="#{col.productFamily}"> </xp:text>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField2" value="#{col.language}"> </xp:text>
        </td>
        <td>
            <xp:text escape="true" id="computedField3" value="#{col.lastModified}"> 
                <xp:this.converter>
                    <xp:convertDateTime type="date"> </xp:convertDateTime>
                </xp:this.converter>
            </xp:text>
        </td>
    </tr>
</xp:repeat>
</xp:panel>
```

Comment: Please show us your code for the repeat. You most likely just need to clear the `value` that the repeat control is using as input.

Comment: I've added repeat code above.

Comment: In the onClick event of the "Search" button I set sessionScope.showResults=false in the error catch.  The panel that holds the repeat control I added sessionScope.showResults !=false.  This way I am able to hide any results that may be in the cache.  It's a work around but it would still be nice to know how to clear out existing results. corrected code above to show what I did.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few improvements you should make/

- bind the `pssrl1` to a scope variable. Instead of going after the control you read/write the scope variable. Could be a managed bean too
- add code to clear the `searchLiteratureBean`. If the collection doesn’t return members the repeat won’t render.

The most efficient way would be to add a get/setSearchString method to your searchLiteratureBean. Bind your search field to that. Have search() and clear() methods and eventually a isSearched() property you can use for the view/hide.

Since you have a bean in place, your markup should only contain data bindings. Makes sense?